# When do you use "is being" in English?

Tags: passive-voice

When should I use *is being* in English?

For example, do you say "something is changed," or "something is being changed"?

Comment: Don't you mean "something has changed" (or something's changed ...). The tense of something is changed sounds wrong?

Comment: You should note that quite often in American speech, "something is changed" and "something has changed" sound almost exactly the same.

Comment: I don't think that we should be closing questions of widespread interest (122,000 page views in this particular case) that were asked in the earliest years of this site (2011 in this case)—long before the "show research" requirement was introduced at this site—on grounds that they don't show research.

Comment: I  concur 100% with @SvenYargs. The question was posted 10 years ago, no one complained about it then. There should be immunity or some type of prescription for posts that are  over 10 years old and have never been closed.

Answer (score 17):

"Is being" is used to describe an action that started in the past and continues at present.
So these sentences have different meanings:

- "Something is changed" describes the state of something; it has changed, maybe recently, maybe a long time ago.
- "Something is being changed" describes the current event that is happening right now; it is changing.

Comment: Is "is changed" correct? I wouldn't say it, although I'm not a native speaker. I'd say "something has changed".

Comment: @Alenanno They're both correct and mean slightly different things. "Is" means that it is currently changed, "has" means that it changed in the past. However, you are right that in the VAST majority of cases you'd use "has changed". See Thursagen's answer for a good use of "is changed."

Comment: @Jeremy: I disagree. Thursagen's example *isn't* a good example of how to use *"is changed"* (though I didn't downvote it). His one should more naturally be *"has been changed"*. A more bulletproof usage would be *"As a general principle, in the animal kingdom, alkaline is changed to acid. In the plant kingdom, acid is changed to alkaline"*.

Comment: @Coomie: Your own explanatory text somewhat undermines your point re *is changed*, in that you paraphrase it as *has changed* (which, depending on the syntactic role assigned to *changed*, could also be *has* **been** *changed*). The form *"is changed"* is normally used when generically describing what happens to some mutable object/property within some process (no specific past/present/future instance being relevant). It doesn't work well for describing the current state of something specific which is now different to what it once was.

Answer (score 9):

One of the uses is simple Present Continuous in passive voice.

> My house is being painted by the workers

means exactly the same as

> The workers are painting my house

Another is a bit more complicated. *Is being* may be used to indicate, that someone (rarely something) at the moment possess a quality that they may or may not possess in general.

> My brother is being mean.

He may not be mean usually, but right now he is. I say complicated, because there are some instances, where *is being* is not used.

> My wife is mad at me

She's not mad at me usually I hope, but she is mad now. Note, that *is being* is not used in this context.

Answer (score 3):

"Something is changed" would usually be used as part of a sentence looking to the future after the change: "When X is changed, we can do Y."

Used on its own, "something is changed" sounds a bit odd; we'd normally say "something is different" or "something *has* changed", which means the change has already taken place.

"Something is being changed" indicates the change is taking place right now; it's roughly the same as "Something is changing."

Comment: +1 for explaining clearly how we might use "is changed."

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: In British English, it is totally acceptable to say the following and the British do that all the time:

John ***is being*** very cheeky today.

Paul ***is being*** rude this morning.

I ***am being*** honest with you.

You ***are being*** modest.

Hence, the present conjugated form of **'to be' + being** is used as a 'continuous present progressive', something that is currently happening.

Comment: I also think that it was added just to be intentionally verbose, and so make it fun to use in sarcasm or express feeling of informally formal

Comment: @Thaina - Agreed, good point!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of grammar, “something is being changed” is Present Continuous **Passive**, it means “something is changing now [by someone]”.

Next, “something is changed” is Present Simple Passive and “something has changed” is Present Perfect in passive voice. So each of this forms means exactly what the grammar tense means, but in the passive voice. The passive voice *is used* (I've just used Present Simple Passive =)) when we want to say that the action is performed *on* a subject, not a subject performs an action.